# php shorten amount of text displayed

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to limit the amount of text/data is being shown from MySQL not MySQL LIMIT but limiting it on the actual page like most blogs do. After certain text point they just display ...more, I know there is a function to do this in PHP but I am unable to remember its name could some one help me out with it?

Comment: Something like substr() ?? (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Comment: But are you going to fetch everything from database on the first place?

Comment: [Visit here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2080871/2260991

it's a LEFT(field, value) function in Mysql

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
if(strlen($text)>1000){
    $text=substr($text,0,1000).' Read more';
}
```

you should understand that it can cut words and tags too.

Answer (score 8):

```
SELECT LEFT(content, 1000) FROM blog
```

If you load entire content for example 30 000 chars and do `substr()`, you are wasting memory in order to show only 1000.

Comment: @John Magnolia, there many more MySQL native functions for strings, check out... http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html

Answer (score 3):

You could use a function like this (taken from http://brenelz.com/blog/creating-an-ellipsis-in-php/):

```
function ellipsis($text, $max=100, $append='&hellip;')
{
    if (strlen($text) <= $max) return $text;
    $out = substr($text,0,$max);
    if (strpos($text,' ') === FALSE) return $out.$append;
    return preg_replace('/\w+$/','',$out).$append;
}
```

This won't cut a word in half like substr.

Comment: Am open to suggestions for improvement :)

Comment: Well if you have 1000 word body, now you have a 1000 elements in an array...  A quick google search came a crossed this: http://brenelz.com/blog/creating-an-ellipsis-in-php/

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do it, the easiest probably being [`substr()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

```
$short = substr($long, 0, $max_len);
```

Answer (score 1):

string substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )

It accepts two arguments. The first is the string that you would like to trim. The second is the length, in characters of what you'd like returned.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Answer (score 1):

Apply the wrap() function to get your shortened text, and replace "99" with the number of characters you want to limit it to.

```
function wrap($string) {
   $wstring = explode("\n", wordwrap($string, 99, "\n") );
   return $wstring[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?

   $position=14; // Define how many character you want to display.

   $message="You are now joining over 2000 current"; 
   $post = substr($message, 0, $position); 

   echo $post;
   echo "..."; 

?>
```

This result shows 14 characters from your message