# Unable to shorten text in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to know how to shorten text generated from the mysql database. I tried doing this by following a few tutorials I found on the internet but failed.

Here is my code,

```
<?php 
$dbh=mysql_connect("localhost","root","root") or die ('Cannot connedt to the Database' .mysql_errno()); 
mysql_select_db("myinfo_db"); 

$res_query = mysql_query("SELECT A.cat_id as cat_id, count(A.cat_id) as cnt, B.category as category FROM listings A, category B WHERE A.cat_id=B.cat_id GROUP BY A.cat_id");

while ($category = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_query) )
{
    echo '<a href="page.php?cat_id='.$category['cat_id'].'">'.$category['category'].' ('.$category['cnt'].')</a><br />';
}

?>
```

Comment: what is your expected o/p?

Comment: You shouldn't use `mysql_` functions anymore as they are deprecated. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead

Comment: question not clear....

Comment: I want to display the results like this "example text..."

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902412/php-shorten-amount-of-text-displayed

Comment: use mysql SUBSTRING() function or use php substr() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the MySQL substring function if I understand your question correctly:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING(sometext,1,10), '...')
FROM sometable;
```

Where 1 is the startposition and 10 the number of chars.

This way you can do it directly and you don't need php to do it.
In your case something like:

```
SELECT A.cat_id as cat_id, count(A.cat_id) as cnt, CONCAT(SUBSTRING(B.category,1,10), '...') as category FROM listings A, category B WHERE A.cat_id=B.cat_id GROUP BY A.cat_id
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm still unable to do this as I'm very new to php. could you please help me a little bit more?

Comment: I made an edit, please try it yourself, it can't be more clear than this :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$res_query = mysql_query("SELECT A.cat_id as cat_id, count(A.cat_id) as cnt, B.category as category FROM listings A, category B WHERE A.cat_id=B.cat_id GROUP BY A.cat_id");
```

to

```
 $res_query = mysql_query("SELECT A.cat_id as cat_id, count(A.cat_id) as cnt, B.category as category FROM listings A LEFT OUTER JOIN category B ON A.cat_id=B.cat_id GROUP BY A.cat_id");
```

To show limit of your comit

```
function limitContent($content,$number) {
 if(strlen($content)<=$number) { 
   $contents=$content;  
 } else {
   $contents=substr($content,0,$number) . '...';
 }
  echo $contents;
}
```

PHP

```
limitContent($category['category'],'10');
```

Comment: There is no difference ?

Comment: `LEFT OUTER JOIN` it is ^^

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm still unable to do this as I'm very new to php. could you please help me a little bit more?

Comment: use like this concat(SUBSTRING(category,1,10), '...') as category

Answer (score 0):

I have [a little class](https://gist.github.com/ikr/7ee8495c05bf032d67d5) cutting long text on a word boundary. So that you don't get something like `Your ass...` when shortening `Your assignment`.

Example:

```
$f = new EllipsisFilter(15);
echo $f->filter('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'); // 'Lorem ipsum…'
```

Feel free to use it.