# How to retrive some lines from particular row in php

Tags: php, mysql

Like its a description column which is long but i want to grab some of lines from it on another page ,

```
 $desc=$result_set['Description'];
```

which is coming from database i want to echo in a p tag but some of its lines not whole description

Comment: substr() is exactly what you want. You can curtail it at mysql end also

Comment: At mysql end:- http://stackoverflow.com/a/2080871/4248328   and substr():- http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_substr.asp

Comment: @Anant wordwrap will not cut short the data, it will usefull to add the  break points only

Comment: @Keerthivasan  i already removed that one, before you said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Substr Function and specify start and end position

```
<?php
$start=0;
$end=50;
echo substr($result_set['description'],$start,$end);
?>
```

Comment: @David, becoz you shoul wait 10 mins from posting time of answer.. its stack over flow constraint..

Answer (score 0):

Use substr(). Something like

```
<?php
$len = 40;
echo substr($result_set['description'],0, $len);

?>
```

This will shorten your description so to a given value (change 40)

Comment: @casper Wyile, you should give start and end to substr function, otherwise it will take only start position, so it will print from 40th character

Answer (score 0):

Use php function substr

```
<?php
$start=0;
$end=50;
echo substr($result_set['description'],$start, $end);

?>
```

And also if the data is coming from a text editor or contains tags then please use the striptags as well. As shown below:

```
<?php
 $start=0;
$end=50;
echo substr(strip_tags($result_set['description']), $start, $end);

?>
```

This will shorten your description so to a given value (change 50)

Comment: you should give start and end to substr function, otherwise it will take only start position, so it will print from 50th character